# Split a unix variable and supply it in a loop

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Lets say I have below values

```
Variable 1 = 12345 45677

Variable 2 = 15,16,17,18 11,10,09,08
```

I want another variable where I can supply to another loop like below

```
15,16,17,18 12345

11,10,09,08 45677
```

What I would do with this value is - I will write this like var 3 = 15,16,17,18 and var 4 = 12345 into a file. Similarly for next row.

I have tried a double loop

```
for I in $var1 
do 
  for j in $var2 
  do 
  echo $I, $j
done 
done
```

what this done is -

```
15,16,17,18 12345
15,16,17,18 45677

11,10,09,08 12345
11,10,09,08 45677
```

Comment: You mention below that you want to read multiple "records" stored in `var1` and `var2`; what is the source of these records?

Comment: The original source is var1 will have 1234 5678 9877 (only numeric) var2 will have 15,16,17,18 11,12,13,14 8,5,6,7 (3 values space separated) I will now run this in a loop which when I say first time it should pick var1 = 1234 var2=15,16,17,18 and second time var1 = 5678 var2 = 11,12,13,14 and so on..

Answer (score 1):

Provided your starting variables are `var1` and `var2`:

```
read var3 foo var4 bar <<< "${var1} ${var2}"
```

OR

```
var3=${var1% *}; var4=${var2% *}
```

Please share the output of `echo $var3 $var4`.

Comment: the second one works - I have put 
echo $var3
echo $var4

**output**
1234 32420
1,2,3,4,5 50,51,52

But I need this in loop as I might have more records in the variable

Comment: I missed a space in the first example, which is fixed now. What is the original source of the information you're trying to parse? I can almost guarantee there's a more efficient way.

Comment: The original source is 
var1 will have 1234 5678 9877 (only numeric) 
var2 will have 15,16,17,18 11,12,13,14 8,5,6,7 (3 values space separated)
I will now run this in a loop 
which when I say first time it should pick var1 = 1234 var2=15,16,17,18 and second time var1 = 5678 var2 = 11,12,13,14 and so on..

Answer (score 1):

Convert vars to arrays and loop through the arrays:

```
a1=( $var1 )
b1=( $var2 )
for ((i=0;i<${#b1[@]}; i++)); do
   echo "${b1[i]} ${a1[i]}"
done
```

Comment: This works as is. But if I want to use 1,2,3,4,5 separately and 1234 separately ?

Comment: I don't understand where `1234` comes from. You can access `a1[0]` for `12345` and access the individual characters with `for ((j=0;j< ${#a1[0]};j++)); do  echo "Position $j of ${a1[0]}: ${a1[0]:$j:1}" ; done`.

Answer (score 0):

Subsitute space separated list with newlines and use `paste` to join them:

```
var1="12345 45677"
var2="15,16,17,18 11,10,09,08"
paste <(<<<$var1 tr ' ' '\n') <(<<<$var2 tr ' ' '\n')
```

will output:

```
12345   15,16,17,18
45677   11,10,09,08
```

You can use `paste -d' '` option to separate the list by space, if you want.

Not you can use any coreutils tool to parse it or even a simple bash while loop:

```
paste <(<<<$var1 tr ' ' '\n') <(<<<$var2 tr ' ' '\n') |
while read -r i j; do
    echo $i $j
done
```

@edit I noticed that in your output `var1` values come after `var2` values. Just switch `1` with `2` in the paste line, like `paste <(<<<$var2 tr ' ' '\n') <(<<<$var1 tr ' ' '\n')` and they will be switched.

Live version available at [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/jkJZES).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to use as below 
paste <(<<<$va2 tr ' ' '\n') <(<<<$va1 tr ' ' '\n')
while read -r i j;do
echo $i $j
done

I get below error in a shell script 
line 48: syntax error near unexpected token `('
line 48: `paste <(<<<$MULT_VAL_STRING tr ' ' '\n') <(<<<$MULT_VAL_ID tr ' ' '\n')'

Comment: the tutorialspoint worked like a charm. But not working in my script

Comment: Not `$va2` vut `$var2`. Add an `|` before the `while`. Add an `;` before the `done`.

Comment: Even after adding | before while and ; before done gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

`awk` way:

```
$ var1="12345 45678 78912"
$ var2="15,16,17,18 11,10,09,08 25,24,23,22"

$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF/2;i++)print $(i+NF/2) " " $i}' <<< "$var1 $var2"
15,16,17,18 12345
11,10,09,08 45678
25,24,23,22 78912
```